# How do you manage the ui-layout of an Ember.js app?

Tags: ember.js

I am looking for options to manage the ui-layout of an ember application I am currently working on.

The application has to be very flexible (configurable) when it comes to the ui-layout - so having layout-containers with regions like "top", "left", "center", "right" and "bottom" which can be nested whould be a good fit (thats how most layout-managers manage layout).

I found a few solutions, but am somehow undecided:

1. [yui2-layout-manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/layout/) ([Demo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/layout/page_layout_source.html))
   Seems a bit old/clunky, successor, yui3-layoutmanager, is in "planning" stage since months (years?)
2. [jquery-ui-layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) ([Demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html#))
   Looks a bit bloated. Codebase is not public: As it seems the project-owner does not want it to be too public(?) (from what i read in the google-group, someone asked why its not on github...)
3. [dojotoolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) ([Demo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dijit_layout/demo/appLayout.html))
   Seems quit a bit "obtrusive"

All in all no solution feels "good" to me and I wonder if I should better write the layout-managing-logic myself. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it: http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jlayout

"[..] The jLayout JavaScript library provides layout algorithms for laying out components. A component is an abstraction; it can be implemented in many ways, for example as items in a HTML5 Canvas drawing or as HTML elements. The jLayout library allows you to focus on drawing the individual components instead of on how to arrange them on your screen. [..]"

Answer (score 5):

Check those two addons:

https://github.com/ghempton/ember-layout

https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager

Also check the demo http://ghempton.github.com/ember-layout-example/

Edit: I think this project: https://github.com/flamejs/flame.js is extremely close to what you want.

Comment: I know ember-layout, but this has nothing to do with automatic screen-space-management (positioning & resizing of screen-regions).

Answer (score 4):

JQuery ui-layout is a problem with Ember, because ui-layout requires a ui-layout-center element at layout time, but Ember {{outlet}}'s typically defer the presence of these.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at Twitter's Bootstrap. It has a layout classes set.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: Developing a jQuery-UI themed application... So Bootstrap is not an option. Besides this I am looking for a full featured layout-manager which supports resizing of regions, show/hide etc.

Comment: jQuery does alot of DOM manipulations which is not good if you want to develop a rich interactive application, I prefer bootstrap which has most of the required UI widgets that jQuery UI provides...At the end it's up to your requirement